# iPhone Notifications is possible to

Tags: iphone, sdk, notifications

I read more post regarding iPhone notification, and I have a simple question....

Where a device receive a notification (so I can display a message contains the message notificatio ti advise the user).
I understand that message is managed by the application.

The question is:

...when my application receive the notification is it possible to start it? 
Or in other world the application became run when receive the notification or it simple became active only to manage the message and at the end of notification management the app return to sleep?
The main application windows is opened on the device ?

Many thanks in advance

Lukenukem
Ciao

Answer (score 0):

With push notifications you can prompt the user to take action, which if they agree (by tapping the "open application" button), will open the application automatically.

The caveat is that you can't do this without the users consent. They have to tap the open application button for your app to open. There's no way to open the app automatically without the user's action, nor is there any way to open, perform the required actions and quit the app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The apps dont "sleep" they are either running or not (till 4.0 OS that is), im assuming you are asking about push notification, what happens when a user receives a notification is that they can choose to close it, or go ahead and "view" the notification which can cause the app to open automatically...thats as far is it goes in the current system i blive...

Comment: Thanks to all...now it's more clear...Do you think that may be more possibility with the 4.0 OS ?